# Problem identifying reflection coefficient at a certain out of band frequency of an amplifier

Tags: rf

Suppose I have an amplifier giving me a certain in-band gain (S21) of say 20 dB .

Now suppose the out of band gain at a certain out of band frequency is only say 6 dB (again S21) how can I calculate the corresponding reflection coefficient at this out of band frequency?

It is clear that there is a relative isolation or reflection of 14 dB (20-6)  at this out of band frequency and suppose I have all the s parameters ( real and imaginary parts) of this amplifier at all frequencies

How can the complex reflection coefficient corresponding to this 14 dB isolation or reflection be calculated?

Answer (score 1):

> suppose I have all the s parameters ( real and imaginary parts) of this amplifier at all frequencies

Then you have nothing to solve.

S11 is the input reflection coefficient. Since you already know it, there's no reason to try to calculate it from S21.

There's also no reason to think it would be possible to calculate S11 from S21 without more knowledge of the nature of the amplifier circuit than you've shared and probably not even then.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be calculated. It could be estimated by simulation from the full schematic of the amplifier. It sounds like you already have all the measurements that you need however.

I could design two amplifiers, each having the S21 you describe, with different S11 out of band. There's no *a priori* relation between them.

If OTOH you had a simple passive filter, then you could derive S11 from S21 and some measurements, and knowledge of the topology of the filter.

Comment: So how can I derive S11 from S21 of a passive filter? or may be I should ask  how can I relate between the two when I have both at a certain frequency?

Comment: @cesar knowing the topology of the filter, S21 would allow you to compute component values, and then from values you could compute S11. At least for a low order filter, measurement errors would frustrate that process for a high order filter. That's why we usually measure S11 of networks, even when we are using them to transport signals for which you might think S21 is more important, as S11 is better for debugging what's going on in the components.